# Including two signatures, both with a 'type t' [Standard ML]

Tags: include, signature, sml

A contrived example:

```
signature A =
sig
  type t
  val x: t
end

signature B =
sig
  type t
  val y: t
end

signature C = sig include A B end
```

Obviously, this will cause complaints that `type t` occurs twice in `C`. But is there any way to express that I want the two `t`s to be equated, ending up with:

```
signature C =
sig
  type t
  val x: t
  val y: t
end
```

I tried all sorts of silly syntax like `include B where type t = A.t`, which unsurprisingly didn't work. Is there something I've forgotten to try?

Also, I know that this would be simply answered by checking the language's syntax for anything obvious (or a lack of), but I couldn't find a complete grammar anywhere on the internet.

(FWIW, the actual reason I'm trying to do this is Haskell-style monads and such, where a `MonadPlus` is just a mix of a `Monad` and an `Alternative`; at the moment I'm just repeating the contents of `ALTERNATIVE` in `MONAD_PLUS`, which strikes me as less than ideal.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hosed.  The best you can do is, as Jordan Lewis suggests, use substructures and a sharing clause.  To `include` two different signatures that both define `t` is always an error.   So mixing `ALTERNATIVE` and `MONAD_PLUS` in the way you would like just isn't going to work.

For a proposal of other things that are wrong with `include` and how to fix them, see [*An Expressive Language of Signatures*](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/pubs/els-abstract.html).

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a sharing clause.

```
signature C =
sig
  structure A1 : A
  structure B1 : B
  sharing type A1.t = B1.t
  type t = A1.t
  val z : t
end
```

This ensures that A1's t and B1's t are the same, and furthermore uses that same t as the type of a value z.

Standard ML '97's grammar is available [here](http://www.mpi-sws.org/~rossberg/sml.html).